# Attribute value is URI encoded on set

Tags: javascript

I want to set an `attribute` of a DOM element using `element["attribute"]`, but the value is `URI encoded`. For instance, if the value is `q=test&r=123&s=456` and after I append it into the DOM, the value becomes `q=test&amp;r=123&amp;s=456`.

Now, view **RENDERED source**, or **Copy HTML** of the script tag using Firebug...

*Please copy paste the code below on a new HTML file for your valuable investigation.*

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript: injectTag();">Inject Tag</a>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <script>
        var injectTag = function () {
            var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
            scriptTag["src"] = "http://www.google.com/search?q=US+Geological+Survey&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a";
            scriptTag["type"] = "text/javascript";

            var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            head.appendChild(scriptTag);
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Now, view <b>RENDERED source</b>, or <b>Copy HTML</b> of the script tag using Firebug...";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

*With thanks and Regards,

Munim*

Comment: Other side-notes: avoid `getAttribute`/`setAttribute` on HTML documents, as it is buggy in IE. Use the reliable and more readable DOM Level 1 HTML properties instead, eg. `scriptTag.src= '...';`. Also, the character sequence `</` is invalid in a `<script>` block (as it looks like the end of the element). Break it up eg. using a string escape like `<\/`. Finally of course `javascript:` URLs are evil and must be destroyed. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is exactly what should happen.

The value is not URI-encoded, though. It is HTML-escaped.

All data (data is: attribute values and text) within an HTML page must be HTML-escaped (`&` becomes `&amp;` in the source code, `<` becomes `&lt;`, and so on). Most browsers are forgiving if you forget to do this, but it is wrong nevertheless.

If you add data dynamically, the DOM just follows that rule and HTML-escapes the data for you.

Comment: +1. Browsers are forgiving and will *try* to fix it, but as soon as you have a parameter name that looks like an HTML entity name (eg. `?...&amperes=3&section=1` (`&amp;`, `&sect;`) you'll get problems. So always `&`-escape your URLs when writing them in HTML source.

Comment: But this fails to load the script. If I set using `scriptTag.src="..."` then it works :S

Comment: @bobince: This just got me thinking. The notable exception of the rule is: the contents of `<script>` tags does not need to (i.e. must not) be escaped - that's why `</script>` is mandatory. What about `<style>` tags? Same thing as with scripts?

Comment: @bobince I cannot unescape my URL, because there's URI encoded contents by intention.

Comment: @Munim: Yes, `scriptTag.src= 'http://www.google.com/search?q=US+Geological+Survey&ie=utf-8&...';` is absolutely fine and correct. What do you think doesn't work? @Tomalak: yep, both `<script>` and `<style>` are “CDATA elements” in HTML, which means there is no escaping, and only the `</` (‘ETAGO’) sequence of characters is ‘special’. In XHTML it is a different story: XML has no concept of magic elements with different syntax, so if you want to use an unescaped `<` and `&` in a `<script>` in XHTML you have to add an explicit `<![CDATA[` section.